# Показать процесс выполнения команды в режиме SSH (Renci SSH.Net)

Tags: c#, .net, bash, ssh

Помогите найти примеры выполнения команд с динамическим вывыодом в реальном времени в режиме SSH, с помощью Ranci SSH.Net

Есть задача вывести команду top (показывает процессы на сервере в режиме реального времени), но при выполнении кода вида:

```
ConnectionInfo connectionClient = new ConnectionInfo
    ("HOST", "USER", new PasswordAuthenticationMethod("USER", "PASSWORD"));
SshClient client = new SshClient(connectionClient);
client.Connect();
Console.WriteLine(client.RunCommand("top -b -n 1").Result);
```

выводится только статический снепшот, а нужно, чтобы информация выводилась постоянно по ходу выполнения команды на сервере.

То же самое касается запуска длинного .sh скрипта, запуск с кода, как выше не покажет процесс его выполнения.
Возможно кому-то уже приходилось решать подобное или хотя бы подскажите в какую сторону копать?

Comment: Подозреваю, что никак, т. к. SSH.NET передаёт потоковый вывод, а утилита top использует curses или что-то подобное (то есть, не работает через stdout).

Comment: Хотя, [вот это](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16543780/276994) даёт надежду.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.
Да, видел этот пример.
Думал, может кто-то встречался с более универсальным решением, т.к. по-мимо top существуют и другие команды для которых нужен динамический вывод(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Моя фряха не поддерживает подключение с паролем, а только через клаву (keyboard-interactive), поэтому я вхожу на сервак немного иначе.

Чтобы консоль могла пережевывать `xterm` управляющие коды, ее надо подготовить.

Вспомогательные структуры и Win API

```cs
[Flags]
public enum ConsoleOutputMode : uint
{
    EnableProcessedOutput = 0x0001,
    EnableWrapAtEolOutput = 0x0002,
    EnableVirtualTerminalProcessing = 0x0004,
    DisableNewlineAutoReturn = 0x0008,
    EnableLvbGridWorldwide = 0x0010,
}

public enum ConsoleStdHandle : int
{
    StandardInput = -10,
    StandardOutput = -11,
    StandardError = -12
}

internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(ConsoleStdHandle nStdHandle);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleInput, ref int lpMode);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleInput, int dwMode);
}
```

И вот такой код получился.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SetupConsoleOutput();

        var authMethod = new KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod("aepot");
        authMethod.AuthenticationPrompt += AuthMethod_AuthenticationPrompt;
        ConnectionInfo connectionClient = new ConnectionInfo("aepot.ru", "aepot", authMethod);
        using SshClient client = new SshClient(connectionClient);
        client.Connect();
        ReadTop(client);

        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void SetupConsoleOutput()
    {
        Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        IntPtr handle = NativeMethods.GetStdHandle(ConsoleStdHandle.StandardOutput);
        int mode = 0;
        NativeMethods.GetConsoleMode(handle, ref mode);
        mode |= (int)ConsoleOutputMode.EnableVirtualTerminalProcessing;
        NativeMethods.SetConsoleMode(handle, mode);
    }

    private static void ReadTop(SshClient client)
    {
        using ShellStream s = client.CreateShellStream("xterm", (uint)Console.WindowWidth, (uint)Console.WindowHeight - 1, 0, 0, Console.WindowWidth * (Console.WindowHeight - 1));
        Console.Clear();
        s.DataReceived += S_DataReceived;
        s.WriteLine("top 1");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
        s.DataReceived -= S_DataReceived;
        s.Write("\x003"); // Ctrl+C
    }

    private static readonly Stream _stdOut = Console.OpenStandardOutput();

    private static void S_DataReceived(object sender, ShellDataEventArgs e)
    {
        _stdOut.Write(e.Data);
    }

    private static void AuthMethod_AuthenticationPrompt(object sender, AuthenticationPromptEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (AuthenticationPrompt prompt in e.Prompts)
        {
            Console.Write(prompt.Request);
            prompt.Response = ReadPassword(false);
        }
    }

    // чтение пароля с клавиатуры
    private static string ReadPassword(bool displayAsterisk = true)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        ConsoleKey key;
        do
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
            key = keyInfo.Key;

            if (key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && sb.Length > 0)
            {
                if (displayAsterisk)
                    Console.Write("\b \b");
                sb.Length--;
            }
            else if (!char.IsControl(keyInfo.KeyChar))
            {
                if (displayAsterisk)
                    Console.Write("*");
                sb.Append(keyInfo.KeyChar);
            }
        } while (key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
        Console.WriteLine();
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Данные в консоли обновляются в режиме реального времени

```
last pid: 35258;  load averages:  0,41,  0,30,  0,27                                           up 139+15:00:15 14:40:24
50 processes:  1 running, 49 sleeping
CPU:  0,2% user,  0,0% nice,  0,2% system,  0,0% interrupt, 99,6% idle
Mem: 39M Active, 1365M Inact, 96M Laundry, 327M Wired, 95M Buf, 136M Free
Swap: 4096M Total, 521M Used, 3575M Free, 12% Inuse

  PID USERNAME    THR PRI NICE   SIZE    RES STATE    C   TIME    WCPU COMMAND
 2732 mysql        47  20    0   935M    37M select   0 416:22   0,22% mysqld
```

Более того, вывод в консоль у меня поддерживает даже цвета в консоли. То есть Midnight Commander выглядит отлично!

Comment: Прикольно! Оно пересылает по целому экрану, что ли?

Comment: @VladD неа, только диффы, но оно клиентом транслируется в управляющие коды локальной консоли. То есть мне не надо дергать курсор или чистить консоль, оно само работает как надо на одном экране.

Comment: Подождите, а у win-консоли есть управляющие коды? Можно сдампить `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Data)` из `S_DataReceived`?

Comment: @VladD ага :) сам сижу прикалываюсь, но есть кое-какие баги, то есть несовместимость с некоторыми кодами. Например вот https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNcDk.png - это скрин с этого же кода, только `top 1` поменял на `mc`. Но я думаю, если глубже покопаться, то и это лечится, я пока не копался.

Comment: @VladD полечил, в `S_DataReceived` поменял `WriteLine` на `Write` :) Остались минимальные артефакты, которые наверняка уже с нюансами перекодировки связаны. https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQBsA.png

Comment: Но всё же, интересно, как win-консоль заставить поменять цвет через Console.Write? Под xterm есть escape-последовательности всякие

Comment: @VladD не знаю оно, или нет, но [вот что нашел](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences). Кажется оно, потому что вот это _The behavior of the following sequences is based on the VT100 and derived terminal emulator technologies, most specifically the xterm terminal emulator._ - многое объясняет, и почему коды xterm зашли в консоль как родные.

Comment: @VladD всё, вылечил окончательно 1) `Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;` 2) `Console.OpenStandardOutput().Write(e.Data);`

Comment: А ещё наверное нужно вызывать `SetConsoleMode`, согласно вашей же ссылке?

Comment: @VladD почему бы и нет, но это уже за рамками данного вопроса.

Comment: Хм, думаю, что без этого вызова в общем случае работать не будет. Не у всех же консоль в режиме совместимости с xterm?

Comment: @VladD я ничего не делал дополнительно, чтобы у меня включился какой-либо режим совместимости. Оно работает и так. Но если вы считаете, что я упустил что-то важное - можете отредактировать вопрос, я только за. Просто сейчас занят уже другим.

Comment: У меня GetConsoleMode возвращает `ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT | ENABLE_WRAP_AT_EOL_OUTPUT | ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING` если запускать из-под Студии. А если запускать не из-под Студии, то возвращает лишь `ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT | ENABLE_WRAP_AT_EOL_OUTPUT`, так что в этом случае скорее всего не прокатит.

Comment: @VladD вы совершенно правы, исправил ответ.

Comment: Поставил бы плюс, но уже стоит :)

Comment: Мужик, ты просто Человечище!
На самом деле в интернете нигде не нашел нормального мануала, а тут на те, полностью готовый листинг.
Благодарю от лица всех страждущих, ты решил большую попоболь не только для меня.
Плюс от меня, решение более чем отличное!