# SSH.NET не выполняется отправленная на сервер команда

Tags: c#, ssh

После успешного создания подключение с сервером отправляю для выполнения команду. Код:

```
client.Connect();
Console.WriteLine(client.IsConnected);
_=client.RunCommand("ironfish config:set nodeName KOLA;ironfish config:set blockGraffiti KOLA;ironfish accounts:create KOLA;ironfish accounts:use KOLA").Result;
```

Данная команда должна выполняться около 30 секунд и изменять конечные значения на сервере(OS Ubuntu)
Но сразу по прошествии 2-3 секунд программа продолжает свое выполнение и переходит уже к следующей команде.
В конце я выполняю проверку, изменились ли значения? Код:

```
string result = client.RunCommand("cat $HOME/.ironfish/config.json").Result;
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

И вижу, что значения остались прежними.

Пробовал специально после выполнения 1 команды морозить поток на 40 секунд, чтобы точно команда успела выполниться, но в конечном итоге значения на сервере остаются прежними.
Скажите, что я делаю не так?
Первая команда успешно выполняется при вводе вручную в терминал

Comment: Наивный вопрос... а параметры коннекта клиента - они задаются, грубо говоря, в предшествующем коде? всякие там имя пользователя и пароль?

Comment: Да, задаются в коде выше

Comment: Вторая команда прекрасно выполняется, а первая вообще ничего не делает

Comment: Что такое `;` в команде, что оно по-вашему делает? Откуда оно взялось? Быть может `&` надо вместо `;`? Или разбить на несколько команд? И научитесь использовать `async/await`.

Comment: @aepot ';' в команде для Ubuntu аналогично '&', поэтому проблема не в этом кроется. Да и await мне особо не помог. Быть может нужно установить непрерывный поток данных с терминалом на сервере? Так как первая команда не просто выполняется и выводит значение, она запускает другую программу на сервере, которая уже вносит изменения в свои параметры.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1277054/373567