# Код работает некорректно, но никаких ошибок нету

Tags: c#, ssh

Я работаю с такой штукой как ОВЕН ПЛК200, моя задача состоит в том, чтобы к ней подключиться, послать туда команду через форму WinForms и на эту же форму вывести результат работы команды.
И у меня проблема как раз с последним:

Я использую такой вот код для отправки кода на эту железку

```
private void CommandSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OVEN_info.Items.Clear();
        SshCommand command = SSHclient.RunCommand(txtCommand.Text);
        string answer = command.Result;
        OVEN_info.Items.Add(answer);
    }
```

В результате работы этого куска кода ничего не происходит - не вылазит никакой ошибки или исключения, но и результат работы команды на форме не отображается. Я решил посмотреть через режим отладки что там происходит и увидел следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть у меня ничего просто не записывается в переменную "answer", а вот почему - для меня загадка.
Потом при дебаге я стал смотреть что происходит с другими переменными, и там увидел следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Меня смущает строчка "Error", где говорится что  команда не найдена (я знаю, что команда правильно пишется ip address, но в таком случае у меня в строке "Error" не ip address, а просто ip, и я подумал что может это из-за команды, но оказалось что нет).
Работаю с библиотекой SSH.NET, и я хотел бы узнать как наладить работу кода.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Если у вас будет в команде не `ipaddress`, а `ip address`, там что будет показыввать: 127 или какое-то другое число после сообщения об ошибке?

Comment: _не вылазит никакой ошибки_ - stdout вы смотрите через `command.Result`, а stderr в `command.Error` не смотрите.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1277054/373567 попробуйте не через `SshCommand`, а через `ShellStream`

Comment: Peter Kolosov, да, будет то же самое число получаю

Comment: Ну после небольшого гугла информации получается я объявляю ShellStream, потом объявляю StreamReader и StreamWriter, и также нужен StringBuilder, правильно понимаю?

Comment: @aepot, Если вас не затруднит, то я тут попробовал написать код, и я хотел чтобы меня проконсультировали, я хочу убедиться что все понял и сделал правильно

Comment: Задайте другой вопрос, проконсультируют